# Unable to Upload Image to Server using Fast Android Networking Library

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image from storage to server. Am I doing anything wrong here? Do I need to use a PHP script for this?

private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask{

```
    File picPath;
    String picName;

    public UploadImage(File picPath, String picName){
        this.picPath= picPath;
        this.picName = picName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String uril = getResources().getString(R.string.ServerPath) + "MyFiles/" + picName;
        AndroidNetworking.upload(uril)
                .addMultipartFile(picName, picPath)
                .addMultipartParameter("key","value")
                .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                .build()
                .setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes) {
                        if (bytesUploaded == totalBytes){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploaded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note the library which you have considers UPLOAD as POST, but if you need to use 'PUT' method your API call will fail and provide you 400, bad request.